# 任意の刻み幅で，任意の最小値と最大値までの配列の作り方

Tags: ruby

Ruby初心者です．
任意の刻み幅で，任意の最小値と最大値までの配列の作り方を教えていただきたいです．

例：刻み幅5，最小値20，最大値85 であれば，以下のような配列です．
`[20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80]`

ご教授宜しくお願い致します．

Comment: [step メソッド](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Numeric/i/step.html) を使うと良いかと思います。`20.step(85, 5).to_a`

Comment: 非常に些細な質問に答えて下さり，ありがとうございます．stepメソッドでやりたい動作ができました．

Comment: @metropolis さん、折角の良い回答なのですから、コメントではなく回答にして、質問が解決済みになる様にされたほうがよろしいかとおもいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[step メソッド](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Numeric/i/step.html) を使うと良いかと思います。

```
20.step(85, 5).to_a
```

<sub>-- この回答は [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49872/%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%88%BB%E3%81%BF%E5%B9%85%E3%81%A7-%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%80%E5%B0%8F%E5%80%A4%E3%81%A8%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%A7%E5%80%A4%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E6%96%B9#comment52001_49872)を回答化したものです。</sub>

Answer (score 0):

もっとエレガントな方法はあると思いますが、愚直に書くと

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
minimum = 20
maximum = 85
step = 5

result = Array.new()
currentValue = minimum
while (currentValue <= maximum) do
    result.push(currentValue)
    currentValue = currentValue + step
end

p result # => [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85]
```

これでいかがでしょうか？

Comment: Чайкаさんの提案法も確認させていただきました．非常にご丁寧にありがとうございました．

Answer (score 0):

```
(20..85).to_a.select{|num| num % 5 == 0}
```